# Automatically set exception on session end - Exception on Control System - Blue Prism

Tags: session, exception, blueprism

I have this Exception on my process. 
I hadn't pending items in the queue and no exceptions appears in the log. The process simply ends after a wait.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: which exception? which process?

Comment: The exception is: Automatically set exception on session end and the process is one that only has to log on a web @Manishh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if a Process with a Work Queue Item locked is stopped without first unlocking that Item, and most commonly occurs when an Exception is thrown without properly releasing the Item in-process.

The Exception is the Blue Prism default applied to any process-locked Work Queue Item on session end.

In your case it seems that you are intentionally ending the process after a predictable outcome, but before actually releasing the currently locked Work Queue Item.

This can be directly remedied in the *Work Queues* Business Object with the 'Mark Completed', 'Mark Exception', or 'Unlock Item' actions being applied to a locked Item before a process hits the End stage.